# How can I remove all the email not in the important or sent folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, imaplib

There are many emails in my All mailbox more than there are in the Important and Sent mailboxes. I want to remove all the mails which are not in the Important or Sent mailbox.

I can not do any of the following steps
1) Delete all the emails in the All mailbox, (when i delete all the emails in the All mailbox, all the emails in the  Important and Sent mailboxes will be deleted at the same time)
2) and copy emails from the Important and Sent mailboxes.

How can I write code to accomplish this?
The problem can become another form:

how can i make a copy of emails in my gmailbox :"[Gmail]/&kc 2JgQ-" into local directory g:\mygmail ?

There are 5 emails in my gmail--inbox ,i save all of them in the g:\mygmails,and name them as 0th.myemail 1th.myemail 2th.myemail 3th.myemail 4th.myemail with the following code,now how can i read them by thunderbird or some email soft ,i don't want to write my own code to read them?

```
import email,imaplib
att_path="g:\\mygmails\\"
user="xxxx"
password="yyyy"
con=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
con.login(user,password)
con.select('INBOX')
resp, items = con.search(None, "ALL")  
items = items[0].split() 
for id,num in enumerate(items):
    resp, data = con.fetch(num, "(RFC822)") 
    data=data[0][1]
    fp = open(att_path+str(id)+"th"+".myemail", 'wb')
    fp.write(data)
    fp.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some digging around on google, I found a [github repository](https://github.com/charlierguo/gmail/) that provides a module for doing just this.  It is not very well documented but the source code is very easy to read so it isn't a significant loss at all.

In terms of using this module, you can load in each email with the specified labels and *mark* them for being saved, then go through all the emails and delete the ones that have not been *marked*.

I don't currently see a natural way to *mark* the emails on the remote server, so you may have to implement something where you record the emails as strings and store them in a `set`.

If you have any questions still, just post a comment to this answer and I can elaborate more.

**For Example:** if you wanted to copy the entries of a particular mailbox into a python data structure, you can do so like this:

```
# Global Variables
username, password, mailboxname = '', '', '[Gmail]/&kc 2JgQ-'

# Set up
import gmail
g = gmail.Gmail()
g.login(username, password)

# Actual code.
emails = []
for email in g.mailbox(mailboxname).mail():
    emails.append(email.fetch())

# Tear down.
g.logout()
```

So assuming that you adjust the global variables accordingly, you now have a python list (in the python variable `emails`) of all the emails in `mailboxname` for the gmail account `username`.  Once you have this, you can easily do something like *saving it to a file(s)*.

Comment: how can i make a copy of emails in my gmailbox :"[Gmail]/&kc
2JgQ-"  into local directory  g:\mygmail ?

Comment: I copy my emails into local directory successfully on my own method iin my edited post,now how can i read them by thunderbird or some email soft?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature If you save it as a `.eml` file, then in thunderbird you should be able to open it by going to File > Open > Saved Message...

Answer (score 0):

If you like [Windows_PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) I have a solution that can be reuse with little effort and customized for your needs. You can setup Mail_User_Agent to use the Web Access API and automate this task. In my examples good old Powershell (as we know already - task automation and configuration management framework from Microsoft) with it's headless IE capabilities (will make it work as a Daemon and allow it to communicate with us only if preconditions are true) is able to support all this. 
    And to be more precise if You have to Login and use Firewall  Web Access APIs - the implementation is almost the same. So with one stone we get two birds - every morning You'll be behind-the-wall and knowing your mail content. Here You can see sample [solution](http://pastebin.com/vVtMqJ47).